# Do snaps require systemd?

Tags: systemd, snap, devuan

Do [snaps](https://snapcraft.io/store) and the [snapd](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snapd) daemon require [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/)? I am running [Devuan](https://devuan.org/) right now, and wonder about the labor required to install applications from snaps.  The [snapcraft home page](https://snapcraft.io/) is content-free when it comes to discussing the subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching for the package with `apt-cache` shows that it is not available for installation, and it can be found on the [list](https://pkgmaster.devuan.org/bannedpackages.txt) of banned packages. It is banned for requiring `systemd` to function.

> Snaps work across Linux on any distribution or version. - https://snapcraft.io (11 Sept 2019)

The claim is not true.

Comment: An efficient solution providing a definitive answer! Thank you kindly, sir!

Comment: Curiously, the one snap I tried with systemd-shim didn't work but it actually launched and its failure mode suggested systemd-shim was not to blame. (It spazzed-out trying to access stuff in my home dir that did not exist.)

Comment: I have just learned that Homebrew is available for Linux. On Linux, Homebrew would work something like snaps, installing software in a user's home directory without involving the root account. https://brew.sh