# pacman target arror

Tags: pacman, artix-linux

I have a new install of Artix Linux (base install) and I am having troubles installing stuff with pacman. Some packages work but zathura, snapd, and most packages don't work.

error: target not found: snapd

error: target not found: zathura

error: target not found: (most packages)

let me know if you need to know any more.

e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probably not in repo. If you downloaded (after 2021-06-09) Artix recently, then you don't have Arch repos enabled, as Artix repos are declared to be self-sufficient. All Zathura packages are in Arch Community repo, see

```
community/zathura 0.4.8-1
    Minimalistic document viewer
community/zathura-cb 0.1.9-1
    Adds comic book support to zathura
community/zathura-djvu 0.2.9-1
    DjVu support for Zathura
community/zathura-pdf-mupdf 0.3.7-1
    PDF support for Zathura (MuPDF backend) (Supports PDF, ePub, and OpenXPS)
community/zathura-pdf-poppler 0.3.0-1
    Adds pdf support to zathura by using the poppler engine
community/zathura-ps 0.2.7-1
    Adds ps support to zathura by using the libspectre library
```

Install `archlinux-mirrorlist` and write this `/etc/pacman.conf` after system, world and galaxy repo. Also add multilib in similar pattern if you use 32-bit stuff (like Wine and Steam). [Official news](https://artixlinux.org/news.php#Arch_repositories_made_optional)

```
[extra]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist-arch

[community]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist-arch
```

Also Artix doesn't use `systemd`, so it cannot use `snapd`, it has hard dependency on that. [UnixSE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541230/do-snaps-require-systemd). Use AUR, Flatpak, Appimage, Homebrew, nix etc.

Comment: archlinux-mirrorlist was already installed and I could not find arch repos in my /etc/pacman.conf

Comment: should I upload the file or is it something dumb.

Comment: @BalboBiggans see edit

Comment: Thanks. It works! I didn't see the mirrorlist-arch so I just added it closer to the bottom.